# Puppeteer- How to .click() a single button out of a grid of buttons with same classname?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, document.evaluate

I'm developing a Nike SNKRS BOT to buy shoes with Puppeteer and Node.js.

I'm having issues to distinguish and `.click()` Size button [screenshot of html devtools and front end buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N1Cr.png)

That's my code: i'm not experienced so i have tried everything

```
const xpathButton = '//*
[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/ 
    div[2]/ul/li[1]/button'
```

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const productUrl = 'https://www.nike.com/it/launch/t/air-max-97-coconut- 
milk-black' 
const idAcceptCookies = "button[class='ncss-btn-primary-dark btn-lg']"


async function givePage(){
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
const page = await browser.newPage();
return page;
}


async function addToCart(page){
await page.goto(urlProdotto);
await page.waitForSelector(idAcceptCookies);
await page.click(idAcceptCookies,elem => elem.click());

//this is where the issues begin
//attempt 1
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('size-grid- 
dropdown size-grid-button"')[1].click());

//attempt 2
const sizeButton = "button[class='size-grid-dropdown size-grid-button'] 
button[name='42']";
await page.waitForSelector(sizeButton);
await page.click(sizeButton,elem => elem.click());
}

//attempt 3   
await page.click(xpathButton)

//attempt 4
document.evaluate("//button[contains ( ., '36')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue


async function checkout(){
var page = await givePage();
await addToCart(page)
}

checkout()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt number 2 looks like the best approach, except your selector is wrong.  The `button` does not have a `name` attribute, according to your screenshot, so you will need another approach, closer to attempt 3.

You can use puppeteer to select an element by with `xpath`, and `xpath` allows you to select by an element's text content.

Try this:

```
await page.waitForXPath('//button[contains(text(), "EU 36")]')
const [button] = await page.$x('//button[contains(text(), "EU 36")]')
await button.click()
```

Because the xpath selector is returning an array of element handles, I destructure the first element in the array (which should be the only match), and assign it a value of button.  That element handle can now be clicked.

Comment: It worked! But i suggest to add :  await page.waitForTimeout(4000);              otherwise it works incosistently

Comment: Yes, waiting for an element is often necessary, but in general, setting forced timeout waits is bad practice in test writing.  Puppeteer exposes some dynamic `waitFor....` methods in their API, I have included an example of this in my updated answer.